# How to fix this IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: c#

My program runs fine, but there is a little problem. When I add new tracks previously existing file to the ListBox, the program experiences an error. The code seems unwilling to do looping in a new file which was added in a different time. Please help me. Thanks ....

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    //...

    string[] files, paths;

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            files = openFileDialog1.SafeFileNames;
            paths = openFileDialog1.FileNames;
            for (int i = 0; i < files.Length - 1; i++)
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(files[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = paths[listBox1.SelectedIndex];
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome, Rida! Please [do some research](http://whathaveyoutried.com) and use the debugger to narrow down the problem, then formulate a more exact question (as shown in [ask]) containing only the *relevant* code. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Adil has caught the cause of the problem, but there's a cleaner solution:

```
foreach (string file in files)
{
    listBox1.Items.Add(file);
}
```

... or even better:

```
listBox1.Items.AddRange(files);
```

In fact, I'd go even further still, and get rid of the instance variables `files` and `paths` completely. I'd either use a `Tuple<string, string>` or create a class for the file/class pair. Then you can add each *complete data item* to `listBox1.Items`, set the `DisplayMember` so that the `file` part is displayed, but when the selected index is changed, fetch the *path* from the selected item. Then there's no need to mess around with indexes at all.

Comment: @radbyx: You'd add a `Tuple<string, string>` for each item in `SafeFileNames` and `FileNames`. That's probably most simply done with the `Zip` LINQ operation.

Comment: @Rida: Then you need to give more information. You haven't even said where the exception is thrown.

Answer (score 2):

You are adding one file less then the files exists, When you will access the last

Change

```
for (int i = 0; i < files.Length - 1; i++)
{
     listBox1.Items.Add(files[i]);
}
```

To

```
for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
{
     listBox1.Items.Add(files[i]);
}
```

**Edit based on comments by OP**

You might be adding the files in listbox more then once by clicking button1. This will add new files in listbox but the arrays will loose previous items in the array and the count in array will become less then the items in listbox.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     listBox1.Items.Clear(); //Clear the items of list box to keep the same items in both listbox and in array paths. 
     if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
     {
         files = openFileDialog1.SafeFileNames;
         paths = openFileDialog1.FileNames;
         for (int i = 0; i < files.Length ; i++)
         {
              listBox1.Items.Add(files[i]);
         }
      }          
}
```

If you want to keep the previous selection then use list instead of arrays as list can grow more easily then the array.

```
string[] files;
List<string>  paths = new List<string>() ;
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{          
     if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
     {
         files = openFileDialog1.SafeFileNames;
         paths.AddRange(openFileDialog1.FileNames.ToList());
         for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
         {
             listBox1.Items.Add(files[i]);
         }
     }          
}
```

Comment: its not working 
for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
{
         listBox1.Items.Add(files[i]);
}

Comment: You just declared reference for array but did not allocated space for the elements. I just updated my answer.

Comment: @Index Was Outside The Bounds Of The Array , am new prgramer at c# and ths prgm maked me mad actually i was tryng to fix this problm since moarning and itz night now but still stuck with this

Comment: Your code is working fine. I think exception is coming because axWindowsMediaPlayer1 is null. Change axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = paths[listBox1.SelectedIndex]; to   MessageBox.Show( paths[listBox1.SelectedIndex]);

Comment: There is only one possibility I found which generates the exception of indexoutofbound. When we add files in listbox more then once by click the button1 more then once. You can select more then one file from openFileDialog by setting the MultiSelect property to true in property window or in code. One of way to get rid of the exception is to clear the listbox on every button click. Put listBox1.Items.Clear(); as first statement in the private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){ listBox1.Items.Clear();

Comment: @ thnx adil itz working perfecly now but i want to add tracts with the previous list item without clear previous list items.. wht to do for this ?

Comment: You better uses list for paths instead of array to keep it simple, I am updating my answer.

Comment: thnk u soooooooooo muchhhhhhhhhh itzzzzzz workingggggg properly now !!! but another prblm occurs tht i used menu strip which contains the function of click . when i click on clear the list gets empty but when i add new tracks in listbox the list box is not playng the track which i selected it plays another track which is even not in the list :s

Comment: You have to clear both listBox1 and paths when ever you need to clear one of them to keep them synchronized. You can clear them by these statements paths.Clear();
                listBox1.Items.Clear();

Comment: You are welcome, Thanks for the compliment, I wish so. I hope you will become good programmer as well. Try to learn debugging, this will be helpful http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/79508/Mastering-Debugging-in-Visual-Studio-2010-A-Beginn

Comment: what do u do ?thnx adil for guidence :) yeah have to learn debugging :)

Answer (score 1):

I think both Jon and Adil are absolutely correct and you can definitely use their code to fix part of the problem. But, my guess is that you don't have any elements in `paths` and so when you try to get an element from it, it throws you an exception. Can you try the following code:

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (paths.Length >= listBox1.SelectedIndex)
        axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = paths[listBox1.SelectedIndex];
}
```

See if you're still thrown an exception and if not, then you have another problem of why your `paths` variable is not being set or why the listbox selected index is greater than the elements in the variable.

Comment: Can I ask you to debug the application and see exactly where the exception is thrown? To debug, place a breakpoint on these 2 lines files = openFileDialog1.SafeFileNames; files = openFileDialog1.SafeFileNames; Then you can step throw code and once you know where you're being thrown the exception, you can post your results here again

Comment: axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = paths[listBox1.SelectedIndex];
got error here

Comment: Next question, what is paths.Length and what is the value for listBox1.SelectedIndex? You should be able to see this by hovering your mouse over them when you place a breakpoint on line "if (paths.Length >= listBox1.SelectedIndex)"

Comment: when i hovering my mouse on paths.Length ,it displays 
int array.length
Gets the 32 bit intiger that represents the total number of elements in all the dimentions of the system.array.
when i hovering my mouse on  listBox1.SelectedIndex ,it displays 
int listbox.selectedindex
sets or gets zero-based index of the currently selected items in a system.windows.form1.listbox1
Exceptions
System.ArgumentOutOfRange exception
System.ArgumentException

Comment: try ?paths.Length and then try ?listBox1.SelectedIndex in the immediate window and post the results again

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the problem is with adding items to the array. The more likely cause is the SelectedIndexChanged event handler. You should bounds check SelectedIndex to be sure it is valid.

```
int idx = listBox1.SelectedIndex;
if (paths != null && idx > 0 && idx < paths.Length)
{
    axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = paths[idx]; 
}
```

Comment: This answers the question directly but I agree that Sheet's answer is a cleaner solution. Don't use the array's at all. Pass both the name and path in the listbox items.